# Minimize absolute difference of two integers

Tags: number-theory, linear-programming

I have 4 known positive variables - $p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$ and two unknown positive variables $x$ and $y$.
How can I choose $x$ and $y$ such that absolute difference of $(p+x \cdot r)$ and $(q+y \cdot s)$ is minimum ?

If this question has been asked before please point me the link.

**Edit:** The values of $p,q,r,s,x$ and $y$ could be up to ${10}^{18}$ and all are integers.

My approach was to write a program to insert values from $0$ to ${10}^{18}$ to both $x$ and $y$ and keep track of absolute minimum difference but I think that will take a very long time.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but you can _always_ achieve zero absolute difference. If $p-q > 0$, then take $x$ to be an arbitrary constant, and take $y = (p + q +xr)/s$. If $p-q < 0$, then take $y$ to be an arbitrary constant, and take $x = (q - p + ys)/r$.

Comment: Do you want x and y to be integers? If not, EuYu's answer solves the problem

Comment: @Alan246 )) x and y are integers. I know the absolute difference can always be minimized to zero.

Comment: @Michael )) See edit.

Comment: @AbhinavShrivastava Please state explicitly that you require integer solutions in the question next time. For integers, its no longer true that you can always achieve zero absolute difference.

Comment: @AbhinavShrivastava, I deleted the **linear-algebra** tag and added the **linear-programming** tag, as I think the latter is more appropriate for this question.

Comment: You are looking to minimize $f(x,y)=|(p-q)+xr-ys|$.Let $a$=min{$(p-q)-\lceil{(p-q)}\rceil,(p-q)-\lfloor{(p-q)}\rfloor$} and consider the equation $xr+y(-s)=gcd(r,-s)$ now you can use Bezout's identity to find integers $u$ and $v$ such that $ur+v(-s)=gcd(r,-s)=k$ since $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ take $u'=-ua$ and $v'=-va$,this is kind the copy paste of the answer i gave just before,still it's just a thought but i hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bezout's Identity says that there are integers $u,v$ so that
$$
ur+vs=\gcd(r,s)
$$
Assuming $p\gt q$, if we let $x=-u\left\lfloor\frac{p-q}{\gcd(r,s)}\right\rfloor$ and $y=v\left\lfloor\frac{p-q}{\gcd(r,s)}\right\rfloor$, then the smallest positive difference is
$$
\begin{align}
(p+xr)-(q+ys)
&=(p-q)-(ur+vs)\left\lfloor\frac{p-q}{\gcd(r,s)}\right\rfloor\\
&=(p-q)-\gcd(r,s)\left\lfloor\frac{p-q}{\gcd(r,s)}\right\rfloor\\[3pt]
&=\mathrm{rem}\frac{p-q}{\gcd(r,s)}
\end{align}
$$
and the largest negative difference is
$$
\mathrm{rem}\frac{p-q}{\gcd(r,s)}-\gcd(r,s)
$$
Therefore, the smallest absolute difference, ignoring which is larger of $p$ and $q$, is
$$
\min\left(\mathrm{rem}\frac{\left|p-q\right|}{\gcd(r,s)},\gcd(r,s)-\mathrm{rem}\frac{\left|p-q\right|}{\gcd(r,s)}\right)
$$